# how to regex the 'metacharacters'

Tags: php, regex

i want to write a pattern for password field that users must use metachars for them passwords (metacharacters like :!@#$%^&*() ), i search about it but didnt find any pattern , is this possible to write such pattern ?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What on earth is a "metacharacter"? Something like John Malkovich?

Comment: Yeah, define "metacharacters". They're still characters, right? So what is so "meta" about them?

Comment: so you mean: non-alphanumeric characters

Comment: That's a trivial regex.  What did you try?

Comment: Here is what PHP says metacharacters are for those who don't know... [PHP: Meta-characters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php)

Comment: yeah , i edit my question , so answer to me . Thanks

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter): _A metacharacter is a character that has a special meaning (instead of a literal meaning) to a computer program_. In a regular expression, most such characters have special meaning -- thus, "metacharacter". In a plain string context, they do not have special meaning.

Comment: You don't really mean metacharacters.  The PHP doc says that meta-characters are characters that have special meaning in a regexp.  You say that you want to require passwords to have metacharacters.  But what you really mean is that you want to require passwords to have non-alphanumeric characters, many of which happen to be metacharacters.  If you really mean you want to require metacharacters, that is the most peculiar password requirement I've ever come across.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a regexp that will match all special characters, you have a few ways you could go:

1. You could write a regexp that excludes alphanumerics:

   /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/
2. You could select the special characters that you are interested in and, carefully escaping the ones that have special meaning in regexps with a backslash, write your own regexp for that specific set of characters.
3. If you know what charset will be involved and if it's reasonably small (so not UTF-8, which will be huge), you can go through it and identify the special chars and then do #2 above.  This might be feasible if you are 100% certain that all data will come in as (for example) ASCII chars.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can put most of them into your regular expression like any other character. For those having a special meaning in regular expressions, prefix them with `\` or `\\` depending on your programming language.

Comment: i put them but its still didnt work :[a-z][A-Z][0-9](\!\@\#\$)

Comment: learn regexp. that one matches for example the string `aA0!@#$`

Comment: @JessicaWatson It should be `[a-zA-Z0-9\!\@\#\$]`.

Comment: yes i know its matche one chars (i know regex) but : aA0! didnt work . Thanks

Comment: @minitech eventually wrapped in `^xxx{5,}$`, what good is a reply if she didn't even read the basics?

Comment: @Anonymouse: What are you talking about? Wrapped? (Besides, it's now "not worked") :)

Comment: @Jessica: no, your regexp matches the full string only. **seriosly, read a regexp tutorial. you don't even know the most basic stuff!**

Comment: @minitech: you ensure only that there is at least _one_ such a character in there. As it accepts `a-zA-Z` that doesn't do much for password safety.

Comment: @Anonymouse: Oh, passwords. I was just giving a snippet. I figured the OP was doing a little more than that. (Maybe not though, from the looks of it.)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the password must contain at least one of those characters, then something like this might work:

```
if (!preg_match('/['.preg_quote('!@#$%^&*()').']/', $password)) {
    // fails
}
```